# Why Oracle discontinued Oracle Java (JDK) Installer PPA?

Tags: apt, java, jdk, openjdk, oracle

I tried to install OracleJDK 8 using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

But it's not working.

I searched the problem and found that

> "The Oracle JDK License has changed for releases starting April 16, 2019." And  "Oracle Java (JDK) 8 Installer PPA (DISCONTINUED)"

So I installed the OpenJDK8 .

But why oracle cancelled the license of oracle 8 installer?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! You should rather ask Oracle instead of the community of Ubuntu users.

Comment: See Jim's and Thomas' answer on [Get error when install Oracle JDK 8 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136104/get-error-when-install-oracle-jdk-8-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @Melebius You  are right but i wanted to ask the ubuntu users, 'cause i am a newbie and i feel  it's giving headeache to the ubuntu users. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle is no longer maintaining OpenJDK 8 and OpenJDK 11. Red Hat is providing bug fixes and security patches for OpenJDK 8 and OpenJDK 11, taking over from Oracle. If you are using OpenJDK from the default Ubuntu repositories, Oracle's license cancellation doesn't matter at all because Ubuntu will continue to support their Java packages the same way they support every other package in their repositories.

Although the Oracle Java packages have been discontinued, Java packages maintained by Ubuntu Developers can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories instead. Run this command to list the available Java packages in the default Ubuntu repositories:

```
apt search openjdk-*
```

A JDK package from the default Ubuntu repositories has a package name `that has the following form openjdk-X-jdk where X` is replaced by the Java version number.