# Unable to add PPA repository in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, java, ppa, repository

So I installed ubuntu 18.04 a few hours ago (a clean installation) but I cannot add PPA repository. I am fairly new to linux but this used to work last time I switched to ubuntu 16.04 .
After typing `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java` and entering my password there is no output for a long time
[image: Here's my terminal after two minutes of entering the command]

after sometime it asks to <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to cancel but doesn't respond to <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and end up saying

`Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.`

[image: this]

Comment: Hello, Actually my terminal is showing any output and that's what I posted as a screenshot

Comment: The second screenshot contains plenty of text. Posting it in a screenshot only makes it not copyable, searchable, etc. See https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals for details.

Comment: This PPA is outdated

Comment: @cmak.fr How can I download it then?

Comment: what you want to install ?

Comment: @cmak.fr Java jdk

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1147022/77093 and this https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: @cmak.fr I installed openjdk... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

with your browser, go to google.com

enter "gpg key servers" with out quotes in the search box

Look through the results for alternate gpg servers

Choose any one you wish, any one should work, put the alternate gpg server in your command

code :

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.your.found.from.google --recv-keys 35DA01C261E46227

substitute "keyserver.your.found.from.google" with any of the alternate key servers listed from your google search.