# installing issue java8

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, java, oracle

sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
when is run this command this shown

```
 sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: This is an obsolete way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Oracle discontinued Oracle Java (JDK) Installer PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147019/why-oracle-discontinued-oracle-java-jdk-installer-ppa)

Answer (score 1):

If you does not have to install oracle version of java8 (you just need some java), try installing it with: sudo apt update && sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk.
Message you got means that apt doesn't know about oracle-java8-installer package that you are trying to install, in other word it doesn't have the repository from which it can download it.

Comment: First of all run this
Sudo apt-get update 
then
Sudo apt-get install java8-jdk
or
you may have instal java through Store just search java jdk and install it